# How to open the push notifications and read the text in Android/iOS device from Appium?

Tags: android, iphone, push-notification, appium

1.When the device receives push how to automate in Appium so that it will open the push notification and read the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am using following code to tap notification with some needed text. you can use it and do whatever needed (did not update code it long time. some parts can be re-written much better. but still working with every phone i tested):

**Page object first:**

```
public class NativeNotificationPage extends Page {

    @AndroidFindBy(id= "com.android.systemui:id/notification_panel")
    private List<AndroidElement> notificationPanel;
    //settings data
    @HowToUseLocators(androidAutomation = LocatorGroupStrategy.ALL_POSSIBLE)
    @AndroidFindBy(id = "com.android.systemui:id/clear_all_button")
    @AndroidFindBy(id = "com.android.systemui:id/dismiss_text")
    private List<AndroidElement> clearAllBtn;
    //last items
    @AndroidFindBy(id = "com.android.systemui:id/latestItems")
    private List<AndroidElement> lastItemsContainer;
    //events data
    @AndroidFindBy(id = "android:id/status_bar_latest_event_content")
    private List<AndroidElement> lastItemsContent;
    @AndroidFindBy(id = "android:id/title")
    private List<AndroidElement> itemTitle;
    String itemTitle_Locator_Text = "android:id/title";


    @HowToUseLocators(androidAutomation = LocatorGroupStrategy.ALL_POSSIBLE)
    @AndroidFindBy (id = "android:id/big_text")
    @AndroidFindBy (id = "android:id/text")
    private List<AndroidElement> itemText;
    String itemText_Phone_Locator_Text = "android:id/text";
    String itemText_Tablet_Locator_Text = "android:id/big_text";
    @AndroidFindBy(id = "android:id/time")
    private List<AndroidElement> itemTime;


    public NativeNotificationPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    public boolean isNativeNotificationPage() {
        System.out.println("  check 'Notification' Screen loaded");
        boolean bool;
        setFastLookTiming();
        bool = !notificationPanel.isEmpty();
        setDefaultTiming();
        return bool;
    }

    public boolean isNativeNotificationPage(int sec) {
        System.out.println("  check 'Notification' Screen loaded");
        boolean bool;
        setLookTiming(sec);
        bool = !notificationPanel.isEmpty();
        setDefaultTiming();
        return bool;
    }

    public boolean isClearAllBtnLoaded() {
        System.out.println("  check 'Clear' button loaded");
        boolean bool;
        setLookTiming(3);
        bool = !clearAllBtn.isEmpty();
        setDefaultTiming();
        return bool;
    }

    public int getLastItemsContentSize() {return lastItemsContent.size();}

    public String getItemTitle(int num) {
        try {
            return lastItemsContent.get(num).findElement(MobileBy.className("android.widget.TextView")).getText();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String getItemText(int num) {
        if (isPhone()) {
            List<MobileElement> item = lastItemsContent.get(num).findElements(MobileBy.className("android.widget.TextView"));
            String tmp = null;
            for (int i=1;i<item.size();i++) {
                if (tmp == null)
                    tmp = item.get(i).getText();
                else
                    tmp = tmp + "," +item.get(i).getText();
            }
            return tmp;
        } else {
            setLookTiming(3);
            if (lastItemsContent.get(num).findElements(MobileBy.id(itemText_Tablet_Locator_Text)).isEmpty()) {
                setDefaultTiming();
                return lastItemsContent.get(num).findElement(MobileBy.id(itemText_Phone_Locator_Text)).getText();
            } else {
                setDefaultTiming();
                return lastItemsContent.get(num).findElement(MobileBy.id(itemText_Tablet_Locator_Text)).getText();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean tapClearAllBtn() {
        System.out.println("  tap 'Clear' button");
        return tapElementInList_Android(clearAllBtn, 0);
    }

    public boolean tapNotificationByNum(int num) {
        return tapElementInList_Android(lastItemsContent, num);
    }

}
```

**Now in test code:**

```
    public Boolean tapNotificationByTitleAndText_Android(String neededTitle, String neededText, AppiumDriver driver) {
            ((AndroidDriver) driver).openNotifications();
            sleep(1);
            nativeNotificationPage = new NativeNotificationPage(driver);
            assertTrue("Native notification page is NOT loaded", nativeNotificationPage.isNativeNotificationPage());

            int itemsListSize = nativeNotificationPage.getLastItemsContentSize();
            System.out.println("  number of notifications is: " + itemsListSize);
            assertTrue("Number of notifications is 0", itemsListSize != 0);
            String title, text;

            for (int i = 0; i < itemsListSize; i++) {
                title = nativeNotificationPage.getItemTitle(i);
                text = nativeNotificationPage.getItemText(i);
                System.out.println("   notification title is: " + title);
                System.out.println("   notification text is: " + text);
                .....
                return nativeNotificationPage.tapNotificationByNum(i);
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: What about iOS? Is this not available iOS, please advice.

Comment: @Aleksei, I have an Appium project along similar lines. Would you be interested in doing contract work for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can open notifications pane using following inbuilt **AndroidDriver**'s method.

`driver.openNotifications();`

If you want to scroll down to a specific Push, use following code -

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("Element Name"));
HashMap<String, String> arguments = new HashMap<String, String>();
arguments.put("element", element.getId());
(JavascriptExecutor)driver.executeScript("mobile: scrollTo", arguments);
```

**Note -** driver is of type AndroidDriver. If not, then you should type-cast it.

Go through this library for better understanding of functions - https://github.com/appium/java-client

Comment: driver.openNotifications() only works for emulators, not real devices and only works in Android, please review:
https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/system/open-notifications/

Answer (score 0):

First things is, what type of push notification you are use.
two type of push notification firebase offer :
1.Notification
2.Data payload.

Comment: 1.Notification type

Comment: When you get notification, your app is in background or foreground.

Comment: both will be helpful

Comment: in both condition you get notification but problem is that when your app is in background you can't handle notification.in second condition you get callback in a service, means you can do whatever you want.

Comment: in a second condition, save text in a shared preference temporary and get wherever you want. So your problem will be solved.

Comment: If you can help me with the code it would be helpful through Appium

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144252/discussion-between-rahul-n-and-nivesh-shastri).